# jqGrid TreeGrid expand node not displaying data in grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

On click of expand node , Trying to get data from server and display child elements. When i click expand the grid gets wiped out.

Here is my script

```
jQuery("#structureBuilderTable").jqGrid({
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
    ExpandColumn : 'name',
    url: '/CoreWebSamples/rest/manageCart/testData',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:["id","Name"],
    colModel:[
         {name:'id',index:'id', width:1,hidden:true,key:true},
         {name:'name',index:'name', width:180}              
    ],
    height:'auto',
    pager : "#ptreegrid",
    caption: "Treegrid example",
    jsonReader : { 
        id: "id",
        root: "value",
        repeatitems: false
    }
});
```

json response from the server  for the first grid, which is shown below.

```
{"value":[{"name":"FirstNode","parent":null,"id":"1","level":0,"loaded":false,"isLeaf":false,"expanded":false}],"message":"Service succeeded.","code":"SUCCESS"}
```

![enter image description here][1]

> First Grid

On click of expand node.

```
{"value":[{"name":"SecondNode","parent":"1","id":"2","level":1,"loaded":false,"isLeaf":false,"expanded":false}],"message":"Service succeeded.","code":"SUCCESS"}
```

and my screen as follows

On debugging grid code. I found

```
if(ts.p.gridview === true ) {
    fpos = ts.p.treeANode > -1 ? ts.p.treeANode: 0;
    if(ts.p.grouping) {
        if(!locdata) {
            self.jqGrid('groupingRender', grpdata, ts.p.colModel.length, ts.p.page, rn);
            grpdata = null;
        }
    } else if(ts.p.treeGrid === true && fpos > 0) {
        $(ts.rows[fpos]).after(rowData.join(''));
    } else {
        $("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(ts.p.id)+" tbody:first").append(rowData.join(''));
    }
}
```

Met the condition

```
else if(ts.p.treeGrid === true && fpos > 0) {
    $(ts.rows[fpos]).after(rowData.join(''));
}
```

After executing this `$(ts.rows[fpos]).after(rowData.join(''));` nothing is happening.

am i doing anything wrong. Please advise

Comment: Which fork of jqGrid and in which version you use? Which value have `fpos` in your test?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. In code i had default scroll : 1,
Because of this on load of child data, The grid was getting blank out. Changed the default grid property  scroll : 0. 
This resolved the issue

Thanks for your response.